# What's a good way to get procedural non-standard gradients?

Tags: texturing, procedural, shader-nodes

Something like this, this demo was done in Inkscape-- basically a gradient that can be morphed into a shape that isn't the standard gradient shapes that come with the gradient texture node (spherical, circular, linear, etc). Is there a way to do this procedurally?[image: Inkscape demo]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Geometry Nodes

[image]

### Shader

[image]

### Modifier stack

[image]

### Result

[image]

### Alternative

As pointed by Gordon Brinkmann, my setup has problems. Solvable by passing the *Distance* directly to the shader, rather than calculating it there:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I ask what that distance node is in the shader screenshot?

Comment: i assume it is Vector math -> distance

Comment: Yep, worked perfectly, thank you! o/

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I would use the _Distance_ output of the _Geometry Proximity_ node. It makes the shader setup a little bit simpler and if I use a different curve where two points come closer to each other it gives weird unwanted results: [curve proximity](https://pasteall.org/pic/aad43e92b69b4197acef705d0a33f6a1)